# How to prove a statement by mathematical induction?

Tags: induction

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for any $x, y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous at 0, and $f(1)$ equals a constant $a$. Show that $f(x) = ax$

The hint provided for this question is to first show that $f(r) = ar$ for $r$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. So I want to express $f(1)$ in terms of $p$ and $q$ and $f(r) = f(p/q)$, where $q$ is in $\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$. To this end, I want to show that $f(1) = qf(1/q)$ by mathematical induction. I am stuck at the step after the inductive hypothesis.

1. For $q=1$, we have $1f(1/1) = f(1)$, so $f(1) = qf(1/q)$ holds.
2. Inductive hypothesis: Assume $kf(1/k) = f(1)$ holds for $q = k$ in $\mathbb{N}$.
3. For $q=k+1$, we have $(k+1)f(1/(k+1))$.

I am stuck at 3. I think I have to express $(k+1)f(1/(k+1))$ in terms of $k$ and $f(1/k)$ in order to complete the proof for this step, and I am unable to show something like that. I feel like I am missing something simple here.

Comment: Why not abandon the hint and instead show that $f(kx) = kf(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$? That would be easier to complete the induction.

Comment: FYI, a few closely related questions are [Properties of Cauchy Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594201/602049), [Let $f$ be a real function such that, for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ Prove that (a) $f(0)=0$ (b) $f(n)=nf(1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327856/602049) and [Checking my understanding of Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797348/602049).

Comment: Since $f(x) + f(y) = f(x+y)$,  for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ you have that $f(nx) = nf(x)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (this is easy to prove by induction). Then we have $qf(1/q) = f(q/q) = f(1)$ for any $q \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't really understand why do you need this to solve the problem but I hope it helps.